# How to remove the select boot option menu, when booting into Lubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu, lenovo, ideapad

I installed Lubuntu on my Lenovo laptop to give some life into it. It works really good, but this boot menu always keeps popping up, and I wanted to know if there is any way to get rid of it? It directly boots into this menu.

[image: it directly boots into this menu]

Comment: are you mean you can not boot to any of boot menu items

Comment: Do note:  If you remove `grub` from showing by default; if you have problems into the future you may find it harder to boot another kernel (*which is done via grub menu*) or temporarily boot with different kernel options which the grub menu allows for.   (*on some hardware getting it to show when hidden isn't easy, thus just reducing the time it waits can be easier for maintenance/security reasons into the future*)

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/A/tips_and_tricks.html?highlight=grub   (*you didn't specify your Lubuntu release; though I get the feeling its an older one from your screenshot, but I detect it sorry, so this may not be the most appropriate manual link*)

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

An editor opens, and you can change the config to your liking. For example, set

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

to always select the first boot option. Save the file, and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to update the boot menu. On the next reboot you should not see the boot menu.